# Twig: render Symfony2 controllers which extend blocks in the parent template

Tags: symfony, twig

Say I'm having a base template like this:

```
// Default/index.html.twig
{% block javascripts %}
    <script>//some script</script>
{% endblock %}

<div>
    {{ render(controller(MyControllerBundle:Default:header)) }}
</div>
{{ text }}
<div>
    {{ render(controller(MyControllerBundle:Default:footer)) }}
</div>
```

And this renders controllers having these templates:

```
// Default/header.html.twig
Header content
{% block javascripts %}
   <script>//some additional scripts from the header</script>
{% endblock %}
```

and

```
// Default/footer.html.twig
Footer content
{% block javascripts %}
   <script>//some additional scripts from the footer</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Is it possible somehow to use the javascripts block from the rendered sub controllers in the parent template?
I want to have all javascripts cumulated in one place.

Rendering from bottom up with extending is no option here because the template consists of 
multiple blocks that are rendered by different controllers.

Is this possible somehow? Or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: do you really need controller to render them?

Comment: I guess this would be the best approach as the included templates have some buisness logic in them and because there are some of them I think they can't extend the base template, do they?. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Anything is possible however design-wise it might not be a good idea.

The `render` tag is really useful when it comes down to scaling and it used as a way to isolate a request. Each `render` call is considered as a sub-request and a cache strategy can be applied to it. 
I'd highly advise you to read this [documentation about HTTP caching](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html) and especially the part that talks about  [Edge Side Includes (or ESI)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#edge-side-includes).

When you use the `render` tag, think of it as a module you want to include in multiple pages and eventually cache.

You shouldn't interact with the master request because the sub request is isolated for caching (depending on the place you embed the render tag, the master request will be different which means you might get some unexpected results).

First of all, I'd create a layout template that every other pages [extends](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html). The layout template will declare all the basic blocks (javascript, css, footer, header, `<head>`, `<body>` - you can abstract in more templates if you want).

If you have logic for your footer or header split them into Twig functions (or filters) and handle the logic in Twig but keep it light (if it's too complicated or too spaghetti that means there is another way).

Avoid having multiple Javascript or CSS files per page. If you have some css or javascript that appears on some pages but not all of them it's still probably a good idea to merge them into one file (less DNS calls on the client side and once it's cached it will be faster to load the page).
If you have a `administrator.js` kind-of file, then you could include it as a separate file but if most requests come from administrators then you might want to include it with all the other files.

If you didn't know you can combine assets (js or css) into one file: more info in the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#combining-assets).

I didn't answer your "how" question because I'd strongly advise you to not implement such a system however I believe I've shared good guidelines to make an informed decision.

Comment: Thomas, thank you very much for explaining the backgrounds behind the render function. I see, that another approach would be better. The problem here is, I'm having some legacy code that used PHP as template engine which I wanted to convert to Twig now. The old PHP templates use a custom function that basically does the same thing as Twigs render method.

Answer (score 1):

when extending / rendering other content in TWIG you can call the parent block: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/parent.html

this means that you can leave default as it is and inside header / footer define

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {# other scripts #}
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

I would suggest that you have different block name for the footer - that way you can include scripts outside of the header.

Also, it might be best to keeps scripts in one place - that way you can use assetic rewrite's later down the line : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-javascript-files

Answer (score 0):

exactly what @Pazi says in the comment: Do you need a controller? It looks pretty simple to just include the template by itself, without using a controller.

You might use the [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) tag to include the subtemplates.

```
{% include 'MyControllerBundle:Default:header.html.twig' %}
```

For reusing the javascript block from the rendered sub controllers, you could create a base template that contains the javascripts block. Then extend that base template file in your header and footer. Or just including the base template in them should work, too.

Comment: The controllers have some business logic in them which is not available to the parent template, so I guess there is no other way than using controllers here.

Comment: Oh... In that case, simply including header and footer templates isn't an option. But the rest of the answer might still help? Did that work out for you?